# Experimental Consequences of $ZZZ$ Vertex

Tags: standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

The gauge boson self-interactions are limited to a relatively small number of possible diagrams in the Standard Model, so in BSM models it is quite common to introduce interactions like a triple neutral gauge boson self-interaction $ZZZ$.

My question is if this interaction is present, what would the measurable experimental consequences be?  It seems like the only involvement would be in a scattering process but this would be swamped out by background processes.  Is this essentially why an EFT approach is generally used where one introduces new coefficients at different orders and then bounds them?